# Insertionsort in Haskell with specified order

Tags: haskell, insertion-sort

i am trying to implement insertion sort in haskell for my weekly university assignment. This is my insert and sort function:

```
  insert :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
  insert a [] = [a]
  insert a (a':as)
       | a <= a'   = a:a':as
       | otherwise = a':insert a as


  insertionSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
  insertionSort   []      = []
  insertionSort (a:as) = insert a (insertionSort as)
```

This works but my tutor specified the signature like so:

```
insert :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertionSort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Everything i tried by now failed and the compiler errors aren't really helpfull either. Hope you guys can help me with this!

Edit:

The given example by my tutor looks like so:

```
Main> insert (<) 3 [1,2,5,7,9]
[1,2,3,5,7,9]
Main> insSort (>) [7,9,1,2,5]
[9,7,5,2,1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use the result of the boolean function parameter instead of a fixed comparison, like so:

```
insert :: (Ord a) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insert _ a [] = [a]
insert f a (a':as)
     | f a a'   = a:a':as
     | otherwise = a':insert f a as
```

Similarly for the other function.

```
insertionSort :: (Ord a) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
insertionSort _  []      = []
insertionSort f (a:as) = insert f a (insertionSort f as)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CFR38690)

Comment: Thank you very much! I read that (Ord a), (>) and (a->a->Bool) are all equivalent. Is that correct? And if yes, why do you need (insert :: (Ord a) => (a->a->Bool) -> a ...) instead of (insert :: (a->a->Bool) -> a ...)?

Comment: @GabbaGandalf None of them are equivalent. `(Ord a) => ...` states that a needs to be an orderable datatype. `(>)` is a function. It is the same than writing `(\a b -> a > b)`. Finally `(a -> a -> Bool)` is a type description: it describes a function that takes 2 values of type `a` and returns a `Bool`.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So the statement (Ord a) => ... just prevents runtime errors?

Comment: @GabbaGandalf The statement `(Ord a) =>` specifies that the type `a` needs to be orderable. The function is a sort, so it makes sense to put that restriction (or rather it wouldn't make sense to sort something that is not sortable). Thanks to this statement, both the developers and the compiler know that they need a sortable list when they call `insertionSort`. I am not sure this explication is very clear, don't hesitate to post a comment requesting clarification (Please use @ so I can be notified of your reply).

Comment: @ThomasFrancois This explication makes sense to me, thank you!